# How To: View placeholder for embedded activities

Tags: android

The Activity screen that I'm working on uses a relative layout to include several local controls along with an embedded activity in the middle.  Ideally, I'd like to configure the relative layout and contained controls within a layout file rather than having to code it manually.  The idea is then to get the placeholder view (via Id) and "fill" it with the content of the activity.

Is there a control or technique for this already?  Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks,

J

Comment: What is an "embedded activity"?

Comment: It's an activity whose view is displayed within another activity.  This is based on a requirement by our client that we allow plugins that they write.  For this to work, the apk's use the same signature and thus run in the same process.  But they control the end product and must write these plugins for security reasons.

Comment: "For this to work, the apk's use the same signature and thus run in the same process" -- that is incorrect. They *can* run in the same process, but simply having them signed the same is insufficient.

Comment: Yes, I know, but we have that part working.  We know how to launch the Activity and get the View.  We can then add that to a GroupView of some sore but I only know how to do that programatically.  I'm asking if we can do it via a view placeholder in the xml layout.

Answer (score 0):

I *THINK* you are looking for the [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html), it allows you to take a layout predefined in an XML layout and then dynamically modify individual parts of it programmatically.  Forgive me if I have misinterpreted your question though, I'm not 100% sure this is what you mean.

Comment: Does that imply that we get access to the Activies resources and then load the layout within a generic View?  I'll have to explore that more.